# How to Quit Current Program and recreate the original Gui? Also creating a secret code to close program

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to figure out how to close the program from a Top.Level Window and then have the program start with a blank slate. Also I am trying to create a secret code combination that completely quits the program. Pointing me in the right direction will be helpful. I created some example code for you guys on the close and recreate buttons that I tried.

```
import Tkinter as TK

font = ('Times New Roman', 14, 'bold')
font2 = ('Times New Roman',12, 'bold')

class example2(TK.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        TK.Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.geometry('380x100')
        self.initalize2()

    def initalize2(self):
        self.grid()

        def restart():
            self.quit()
            main()

        Yes = TK.Button(self, text = 'Yes', font = font2, command = restart)
        Yes.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = 'we', padx = (10, 10))

class example(TK.Tk):   
    def __init__(self, parent):
        TK.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid() 

        def gatherinfo():
            example2()

        MSubmit = TK.Button(self, text = 'Submit', font = font2, command = gatherinfo)
        MSubmit.grid(column = 3, row = 3, sticky = 'we', padx = (10, 10))

def main():
    app = example(None)
    app.geometry('400x400')
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It seems to skip the quit command and just go to the rebuild command. Thanks in advance.

Updated Code:

```
import Tkinter as TK
import sys

font = ('Times New Roman', 14, 'bold')
font2 = ('Times New Roman',12, 'bold')

class example3(TK.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        TK.Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.geometry('380x100')
        self.parent = parent
        self.initalize3()

    def initalize3(self):
        self.grid()

        def restart():
            self.parent.do_restart = True
            self.parent.destroy()

        #Creates Label Frame
        NstepOne = TK.LabelFrame(self, font = font2)
        NstepOne.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)      

        #Creates Buttons
        Yes = TK.Button(NstepOne, text = 'Yes', font = font2, command = restart)
        Yes.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = 'we', padx = (10, 10))

class example2(TK.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        TK.Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.geometry('770x150')
        self.parent = parent
        self.initalize2()

    def initalize2(self):
        self.grid()

        #Creates Label Frame
        MstepOne = TK.LabelFrame(self, font = font2)
        MstepOne.grid(row=0, columnspan=7, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

        def gatherinfo2():
            self.destroy()
            example3(self)

        #Creates Label 
        MLabel1 = TK.Label(MstepOne, text = "First Name", font = font)
        MLabel1.grid(column = 2, row = 0, sticky = 'w', padx = (10, 10))
        MLabel2 = TK.Label(MstepOne, text = "Last Name", font = font)
        MLabel2.grid(column = 4, row = 0, sticky = 'w', padx = (10, 10))

        #Creates Button
        MSubmit = TK.Button(self, text = 'Submit', font = font2, command = gatherinfo2)
        MSubmit.grid(column = 3, row = 3, sticky = 'we', padx = (10, 10))

class example(TK.Tk):   
    def __init__(self, parent):
        TK.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.do_restart=True
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid() 

        def gatherinfo():
            example2(self)

        def terminate(event = None):
            self.do_restart = False
            self.destroy()            

        self.bind("<Escape>", terminate) # Press ESC to escape the program
        MSubmit = TK.Button(self, text = 'Submit', font = font2, command = gatherinfo)
        MSubmit.grid(column = 3, row = 3, sticky = 'we', padx = (10, 10))

def main():
    do_loop = True        # Loop so we can restart the program if not terminating it
    while do_loop:
        app = example(None)
        app.geometry('400x400')
        app.mainloop()
        do_loop = app.do_restart # Gets if we should restart or terminate


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have changed the code as such:

```
import Tkinter as TK

font = ('Times New Roman', 14, 'bold')
font2 = ('Times New Roman',12, 'bold')

class example3(TK.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        TK.Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.geometry('380x100')
        self.parent=parent
        self.initalize()

    def initalize(self):
        self.grid()

        def restart():
            self.parent.do_restart = True
            self.parent.destroy()

        Yes = TK.Button(self, text = 'Yes', font = font2, command = restart)
        Yes.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = 'we', padx = (10, 10))

class example2(TK.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        TK.Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.geometry('770x150')
        self.parent = parent
        self.initalize()

    def initalize(self):
        self.grid()

        #Creates Label Frame
        MstepOne = TK.LabelFrame(self, font = font2)
        MstepOne.grid(row=0, columnspan=7, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

        def gatherinfo2():
            #self.destroy() #Not sure why your do this
            example3(self.parent) # You need to pass self.parent here

        #Creates Label 
        MLabel1 = TK.Label(MstepOne, text = "First Name", font = font)
        MLabel1.grid(column = 2, row = 0, sticky = 'w', padx = (10, 10))
        MLabel2 = TK.Label(MstepOne, text = "Last Name", font = font)
        MLabel2.grid(column = 4, row = 0, sticky = 'w', padx = (10, 10))

        #Creates Button
        MSubmit = TK.Button(self, text = 'Submit', font = font2, command = gatherinfo2)
        MSubmit.grid(column = 3, row = 3, sticky = 'we', padx = (10, 10))


class example(TK.Tk):   
    def __init__(self, parent):
        TK.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.do_restart=True
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid() 

        def gatherinfo():
            example2(self)

        def terminate(event=None):
            self.do_restart = False
            self.destroy()            

        self.bind("<Escape>", terminate) # Press ESC to escape the program
        MSubmit = TK.Button(self, text = 'Submit', font = font2, command = gatherinfo)
        MSubmit.grid(column = 3, row = 3, sticky = 'we', padx = (10, 10))

def main():
    do_loop = True        # Loop so we can restart the program if not terminating it
    while do_loop:
        app = example(None)
        app.geometry('400x400')
        app.mainloop()
        do_loop = app.do_restart # Gets if we should restart or terminate
        if do_loop:
            print("Restarting")
        else:
            print("Terminating")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The right approach IMHO - no globals and passing objects as arguments.

Comment: How would you restart the entire application if you have a third window? Is it possible? When I run this code with the top level it kills the second pop up window but not the first.

Comment: Not sure I understand. The code above will remove both windows, but the main window (with the Submit button) will be shown again due to the restart. I fixed the terminate function as it was lacking the event=None. Could you explain how you add a third window?

Comment: Updated answer, is this what you mean? A bit unclear to me what you try to do.

Comment: Works perfectly. What will happen is the user will submit information. It checks to see if it can find their information, if it can't it has another pop up and a third pop to ask them another question. I hope that clears up what I was trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change `self.quit()` to `app.destroy()` and have to globalise `app` in `main()` and in `restart`

```
import Tkinter as TK

font = ('Times New Roman', 14, 'bold')
font2 = ('Times New Roman',12, 'bold')

class example2(TK.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        TK.Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.geometry('380x100')
        self.initalize2()

    def initalize2(self):
        self.grid()

        def restart():
            global app
            app.destroy()
            main()

        Yes = TK.Button(self, text = 'Yes', font = font2, command = restart)
        Yes.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = 'we', padx = (10, 10))

class example(TK.Tk):   
    def __init__(self, parent):
        TK.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid() 

        def gatherinfo():
            example2()

        MSubmit = TK.Button(self, text = 'Submit', font = font2, command = gatherinfo)
        MSubmit.grid(column = 3, row = 3, sticky = 'we', padx = (10, 10))

def main():
    global app
    app = example(None)
    app.geometry('400x400')
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

hope that helped you!

Comment: Uggh - suggesting anyone should use globals - shuddder !

Comment: Yes I know, but globals can be handy, where would it go wrong here?

Comment: Maybe in this small script they would work, but I would caution against using them ever - they are a bad habit which is difficult to break for some people and a pain to debug when they go wrong, and finally as PrebenR proved, simply not needed.